# How to manually set an object state to clean (saved) using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### Explanation:

I'm using ember-data for a project of mine and I have a question that revolves around the possibility of dirtying an object and then setting its state to clean again on purpose - without commiting the changes. The scenario is this:

Say I've fetched an object via `banana = App.Fruit.find('banana');` and it has a description of "Yellow fruit!". Using XHR long-polling (or WebSockets), I may receive an updated version of the object because of another user having changed the description to "A tasty yellow fruit!" at any given point in time *after* I fetched the original object.

Then, what I would like to do is to update the object to reflect the newly received data. For this, I've tried different approaches:

- I've tried calling `App.Store.load(App.Fruit, new_data);`. First of all, this approach doesn't work and secondly, this is not really what I want. I could've made uncommitted changes to the object myself and in this case, it would be undesirable to just discard those (assuming the `load()` call would overwrite them).
- I've tried looping through the new data, calling `.set()` - like so: `banana.set('description', new_data.description);` - in order to update the object properties with the new data (where applicable = not dirty). This works but it leaves the object in a dirtied state.

In order to make the object clean/updated again - and **not** have the adapter commit the changes! - I've taken a look at the states the object travels through. These are (at least):

- Step 1: Initially, the object is in the `rootState.loaded.saved` state.
- Step 2: Calling `.set()` on a property pushes it to the `rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted` state.
- Step 3: Calling `App.store.commit();` returns the object to the `rootState.loaded.saved` state.

Therefore, I've tried to manually set the object state to `saved` after step 2 like so: `banana.get('stateManager').goToState('saved');`.

However, this doesn't work. The next time the store commits for any other reason, this maneuver produces an *inFlightDirtyReasons is undefined* error.

### Question:

My question is: how can I manually change the state of a dirtied object back to clean (saved) again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at ember-data the uncommitted state has a 'becameClean' event which consequently sets the record as loaded.saved.

This should do the trick

```
record.get('stateManager').send('becameClean');
```

Comment: I've written a blog post about this that may be of help to others: http://www.kaspertidemann.com/how-to-manually-change-the-state-of-a-dirtied-ember-data-object/

Comment: `Error: Attempted to handle event 'becameClean' on <App.User:ember255:1> while in state rootState.error` What now?

Comment: Seems like it now calls `rootState.loaded.materializing`

Comment: Any updates on @Intentss' issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: intenss has a response below that worked for me. Now the problem is loading associated models as well. It doesn't seem to recognize that they're present, too.

Comment: This is obsolete, use @kamil-j's solution below.

Answer (score 24):

Solution for **Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.7**:

```
// changing to loaded.updated.inFlight, which has "didCommit" 
record.send('willCommit'); 
// clear array of changed (dirty) model attributes
record.set('_attributes', {});
// changing to loaded.saved (hooks didCommit event in "inFlight" state)
record.send('didCommit');
```

I've searched the source code of Ember-data and I've found that loaded.saved state has a setup function that checks whether a model is clean, before setting "saved" state. If it is not clean, then it rejects a request to change state and  returns to loaded.updated.uncommitted.

So you have to clean **model._attributes** array, which keeps attributes names and Ember will let you change state manually.

I know it isn't very good solution, because is needed to set private property of a model, but I've not found any other solutions yet.

Comment: This is the only solution compatible with 1.0.0-beta.9. Thanks for this.

Comment: Works with 1.0.0-beta.15

Comment: This does not seams to work with EmberJS Data 2.3.0. The records are still dirty in the EmberJS Inspector.

Comment: @Charles I've run into the same problem. Did you end up finding a solution for it?

Comment: It think I ended using `this.get('store').pushPayload(data);`. I'm not sure this works for your use case. I don't have exactly the same issue as the author of the question.

Answer (score 10):

Solution for **Ember Data 2.6.1**

```
record.send('pushedData');
```

set dirty record as loaded and saved

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/fec260a38c3f7227ffe17a3af09973ce2718acca/addon/-private/system/model/states.js#L250

Answer (score 7):

It's an update to @Kamil-j's solution.

For Ember Data 2.0 which I am currently using I have to do the following:

```
record._internalModel.send('willCommit'); 
record._internalModel._attributes = {};
record._internalModel.send('didCommit');
```

Comment: I had to use `record.get('_internalModel')` for ED 2.0.1

Answer (score 5):

As of 1.0.0.rc6.2....

This will move a model into the state of a model that has been saved.

```
record.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.saved')
```

This will moves a model to a the state of a new model that has not been committed. Think new dirty model.

```
record.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.created.uncommitted')
```

This will move a model into the sate of an old model that has been updated, think old dirty model:

```
record.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.updated')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's "loaded.created.uncommitted", not "loaded.created.uncommited". Notice an extra "t" in "uncommitted".

Comment: Just a quick headsup that this doesn't work in ember rc7. Not sure what the alternative is. Still looking....

Answer (score 5):

As of `ember-data` `1.0.0-beta.12:`

```
record.transitionTo('loaded.saved');
```

It seems that **`record.get('stateManager')`** is not required anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what seems to work for Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.10:

```
record.set('currentState.stateName', 'root.loaded.saved');
record.adapterWillCommit();
record.adapterDidCommit();
record.set('currentState.isDirty', false);
```

Not sure if all those lines are required but just following what others have done prior to this.

Comment: It worked for me just with record.set('currentState.isDirty', false);

Answer (score 3):

**Ember 2.9.1**

```
record.set('currentState.isDirty', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Tested on Ember Data 2.9**

pushedData action is the way to go but besides that the "originalValues" need to be reset as well.

```
Ember.assign(record.data, record._internalModel._attributes);
Ember.assign(record._internalModel._data, record._internalModel._attributes);
record.send('pushedData');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like with newer versions everything methioned here got broken.

This worked for me with ***ember-data 1.0.0.beta4:***

```
record.adapterWillCommit();
record.adapterDidCommit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method that worked for me when using Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.18:

`record.rollback()`

This reversed the dirty attributes and returned the record to a clean state.

Seems like this may have been since deprecated in favor of `record.rollbackAttributes`: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_rollbackAttributes

Answer (score 1):

I work on **Ember data 1.13** so I used the following solution (which seems a mix between the one provided by @Martin Malinda and the other by @Serge):

```
// Ensure you have the changes inside the record
Object.assign(record.data, record._internalModel._attributes);
Object.assign(record._internalModel._data,record._internalModel._attributes);

// Using the DS.State you can first simulate the record is going to be saved
record.get('_internalModel').send('willCommit');

// Cleaning the prevous dirty attributes
record.get('_internalModel')._attributes = {};

// Mark the record as saved (root.loaded.created.uncommitted) even if it isn't for real
record.get('_internalModel').send('didCommit');
```

In this way, if we will call a further `rollbackAttributes()` on this record, if we will have some dirty attributes, the record will be reset to this last state (instead of having the original properties) which was exactly what I was looking for in my use case.

If we won't have any dirty attributes, nothing will change and we will keep the last attributes set using this code without having them rolled back to the original ones. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested on Ember Data 3.8.0**

Just an update to Martin Malinda's  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40605235/5981205):

```
// Clear changed attributes list 
record._internalModel._recordData._attributes = {};

// Trigger transition to 'loaded.saved' state
record.send('pushedData');
```

In my case I also needed to override serializer's `normalize` method.