# Ember Data: how to set isDirty for a record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a `details: DS.attr('recursive_object')` custom transformation (it's a recursive object).

The `details` attr can be edited in place, without the actual object reference changing (e.g., a sub-detail on the details attr is edited). This, however, doesn't trigger the parent record's `isDirty` flag.

**How can I manually notify a DS.Model record that it's been updated?**

Model definition:

```
App.MyRecord = DS.Model.extend
  details: DS.attr "recursive object"
```

Editing  `details`

```
# record is an instance of App.MyRecord
# makes a change to the record's details attr 
record.makeChangeToDetails()
record.get('isDirty') # still false because Ember doesn't know that a sub-detail changed.
```

**Things I've tried:**

Wrapping `record.makeChangeToDetails()` with `will/didSetProperty` calls:

```
record.send 'willSetProperty', name: 'details'
record.makeChangeToDetails()
record.send 'didSetProperty', name: 'details'
```

Calling `notifyPropertyChange`

```
record.notifyPropertyChange 'details'
```

Calling `set` and passing it the same object

```
record.makeChangeToDetails()
record.set 'details', record.get('details')
```

I've also tried sending various other DS.model states events from here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/states.js
 including `didChangeData`, `becameDirty`  but none of these worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I got some clues from this other question: [How to manually set an object state to clean (saved) using ember-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342250/how-to-manually-set-an-object-state-to-clean-saved-using-ember-data?rq=1)

In particular, the bit about:

`record.get('stateManager').transitionTo('loaded.saved')`

Answer (score 3):

Using `1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba`, this appears to do the job:

```
> record.isDirty()
< false
> record.send('becomeDirty')
< undefined
> record.isDirty()
< true
```