# Force ember-data to re-load specific record from server

Tags: javascript, json, rest, ember.js, ember-data

Lets say I have 2 nested resources for posts. It is defined like this in my router.

```
this.resource('posts', function () {
    this.resource('post', {path: '/:post_id'});
});
```

Each post can then also have multiple related comments.

In my *posts_route.js* i set up the model like this:

```
return this.get('store').findAll('post');
```

This makes a GET request to my backend api which returns all posts as json. At this point I only need basic information (and no comments), so not all the data is included in the returned json. Later, if I click on a specific post I do this in my *post_route.js*:

```
return this.get('store').find('post', params.post_id);
```

With this I wish to do a new GET request for only that specific post. But ember-data does not do a new server request. I looks for it in the local store where it finds it, but not with the extended data I was hoping to get.

Is there a way to force ember-data to do a real request to the server? Thanks.

Comment: What if you first set the post item dirty? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158329/ember-data-how-to-set-isdirty-for-a-record

Comment: @DelphiLynx Thanks for your response. I like your idea, but I can't get it to set the post to dirty. Should try making it dirty in my post_route just before I do find('post', params.post_id)?

Comment: @DelphiLynx I ended up solving my problem finally. The problem was actually a bit different from how I presented it. I will edit my question and write how I solved it tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: @@Oscar, what I also did in an application was to have a custom Dirty boolean property in my object. That way I could set the whole model dirty to just toggle that property. Just an idea :)

Comment: @DelphiLynx I came to work to day feeling all good having fixed the problem. Then I found out that the external api that the backend is using would not support it. So I'm going to go for toggling a dirty boolean like you suggested. Seems like the way to go right now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `model.reload()` to force a new GET request to the show route. You could do this in the `afterModel` hook or the `setupController` hook of your show route. If you really don't want to trigger this request again if the model has already been loaded, you can just define a plain old `reloaded` property on your model:

```
MyModel = DS.Model.extend({
   ... attributes ...
   reloaded: false
})
```

And then set that to `true` when the reload completes:

```
model.reload().then(function(response) { model.set('reloaded', true'); });
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick_Ragaz! You're answer was clear and solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

A way to force ember-data to do a real request to the server would be like this:

`store.findRecord('post', 1, { reload: true })`