# Ember js how to force reload of specific selected record?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014643/force-ember-data-to-re-load-specific-record-from-server) but do not understand how it applies to my situation, since I have no 'show' route.

I inherited this app, and the router.js looks like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {
    path: '/'
  });
  return this.resource('parent', {
    path: '/:parent_id'
  }, function() {
    this.resource('games', {
      path: '/games'
    });
    return this.resource('game', {
      path: '/game/:game_id'
    });
  });
});
```

The backend is Rails, and when the /games url is hit in Ember, it calls the games Index action in the Rails GamesController, as expected.

The games template renders each game:

```
<ul class="gamesList">
{{#each game in sortedGames}}
  {{#link-to 'game' game class='gameItem u-cf' tagName='li'}}
    <div class="gameItem-name u-before6of12 u-after1of12">{{game.name}}</div>
    <div class="gameItem-description u-before6of12 u-after1of12">{{game.description}}</div>
  {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

but when the game link is clicked, it loads the game from Ember store, and does not make a request to the API.

I need it to make a request to the API because:
1. The list of games includes only name and description, since the list can include many games, so we only want to load a subset of the data for each game.
2. An individual game, loaded by the Rails Show action, should use a different serializer to load all the additional content for a single game (including embedded child objects).

This is the Games route:

```
App.GamesRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Easypeasy.ResetScroll, {
  model: ->
    return this.store.find('game', {
      parent: @modelFor('parent').get('slug')
    })
})
```

and this is the Game route:

```
App.GameRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.ResetScroll)
```

How do I trigger Ember to load the single game that the user clicks on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So ember data by default will not re-request data that it has already loaded. If your parent route's model loaded an array of games, then the child route that requires a specific game will not make another request. The following code

```
this.store.findRecord('game', params.game_id)
```

will simply look inside the in-memory ember-data store and return the game record.

In cases where you need to make another request, you can force the behavior via an option

```
this.store.findRecord('game', params.game_id, {reload: true});
```

You can read about this behavior here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_findRecord

Do note that I am linking to ember 2.0 docs, but this works with ember data 1 as well. If you are using ember data < 2.0, your call will probably look like this

```
this.store.find('game', params.game_id, {options: reload});
```

Another way to do this is to call `reload()` on the model instance itself. This will also prove useful if you know that data has change on the server, and you want to re-request data for a model after some action has occurred.

And finally, Ember Data 2.0 provides even more options, where you can quick load data from the store, but also make a request in the background to fetch more info. This can be either good or bad depending on whether you want your users to see a flash of missing content, or whether you want them to wait.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but what I find strange is nowhere in the code is this line: this.store.findRecord('game', params.game_id).  If it is not doing a findRecord, how is it loading it from the store?  I tried adding that to the GameRoute (which you can see above is basically empty) but that gives an error (cannot read property 'find' of undefined)

Comment: Sorry it gives this error: Error while processing route: game this.store.findRecord is not a function - I guess this is because I am on ember 1.12.  So I tried your proposed line for ember < 2.0 and get this error: Error while processing route: game params is not defined

Comment: Ok I fixed that error by adding params to the function parameters, now I get another error:  game reload is not defined

Comment: Finally found the solution by reading this: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/force-store-to-reload-data-from-api/4441/16
Need to pass the game.id from the games list template, not the full game model. Then had to use fetchById, not find.