# Why isDirty() return always true even if my data is saved?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage

Check out this code, this is my model:

```
App.Partita = DS.Model.extend({
    data: DS.attr('string'),
    ora: DS.attr('string'),
    evento: DS.attr('string'),
    segno: DS.attr('string'),
    quota: DS.attr('number'),
    vinto: DS.attr('boolean', false),
    giocata: DS.attr('number'),
    vincita: DS.attr('number'),
    cassa: DS.attr('number'),
    remove: DS.attr('boolean', false),

    remover: function () {
        this.deleteRecord();
    this.save();
    }.observes('remove', true),

    vintoChange: function () {
       console.log(this);
       console.log(this.get('isDirty'));
       if(!this.get('isDirty'))
    this.save();
    }.observes('vinto')

});
```

and I'm using localstorage adapter for the data:

```
App.LSAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({
namespace: 'app_namespace'
});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter;
```

I don't know why but when the function "vintoChange" is triggered, I always get that the data is dirty even if it was saved before with

```
.get('model').save();
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: Check the other Q&A, there are a lot of them mentioning isDirty flag. Maybe this one could help [How to manually set an object state to clean (saved) using ember-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342250/how-to-manually-set-an-object-state-to-clean-saved-using-ember-data?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's saving?  You aren't actually validating that it saved.  I would bet server side you are happy with the data sent, but client side ember data is throwing an error on the data it got back from the server.

```
var savePromise = this.save();

savePromise.then(
   function(){ alert('saved'); }, 
   function(){ alert('failed to save'); }
 );
```