# Attempted to handle event `becameInvalid` while in state 'root.loaded.saved'

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I've implemented [DS.Errors](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html) for my RestAdapter, thanks to Alex Spellers tutorial on [server side validation](http://alexspeller.com/server-side-validations-with-ember-data-and-ds-errors/).

However, in this part of my app I want to do a simple client side check to see if the form is complete. (Why not have DS.Errors handle all the errors?)

```
  process: function(upload) {
    var form = upload.get('form');

    if (!isComplete(form)) {
        upload.get('errors').add('field', 'field isempty'); 
        return;
    }
    // else "Processing..."
```

The logic here is somewhat simplified, but [errors.add()](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Errors.html#method_add) should invalidate, and add an error to the model. However I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `becameInvalid` on <@model:upload:54a1f298ef912a2ace760b0f> while in state root.loaded.saved.
```

I have read about the state manager, but am unsure as to how, and what state I should transition to before adding an error to my model.

Thanks in advance!

```
Ember      : 1.8.1
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.11
Handlebars : 1.3.0
jQuery     : 1.11.2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After revisiting this I came across the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23344215/2778150). What solved my problem was not sending `willCommit`, but sending `upload.send('becomeDirty');` before executing the following:

```
upload.get('errors').add('field', 'field isempty');
```

Now errors can be added as the upload model is not in the `saved` state.